# frequently hangs the browser while manipulating pivot table when input data is big

Tags: javascript, browser, crash, pivottable.js

when manipulating pivot table, as selecting rows/columns, frequently hangs the browser when  input data is big.
Browser  crashes frequently(Browser started to complain it was out of memory), 
For the input data, I'm only passing in the array under the data key As below.

`[{"Province": "d6880daca6180e00", "Party":"Conservative", "Age": 50,"Name": "8c9424ca352f92c7","Gender": "Male","City":"83f113b91833ae43","Country":"india","Brand":"AcnSports","Account":"Old Navy LLC","Tier 1 SC Access":"Update","Province1": "Ontario", "Party1":"Conservative1", "Age1": 50,"Name1": "Adle Mark", "Gender1": "Male","City1":"Jaipur","Country1":"india","Brand1":"AcnSports","Account1":"Old Navy LLC","Tier 1 SC Access1":"Update"}]`

**I have 5k rows which contains unique value for(Key) -Provience,Name and City ,rest all are duplicate.**
Everything seems working. Data gets rendered but it takes too much time whenever I perform any action like drag n drop.
It works fine if there is all  duplicate rows ,I have tested for 1,60000 records and it works smooth .
Please correct me If I  am doing anything wrong. 
What should I do in this case?
Any Help will be apprecited.

[output table Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYJ1Q.jpg)

[JSONData](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5tB3Kj8ObvSTHNLQnp6cWwtYk0/view?usp=sharing)
**System spec's :-**  2.5 Ghz, Core i7,16 GB Ram,Chrome

Thanks,
Ravindra Solanki

Answer (score 0):

This issue was addressed in Github Issues :) https://github.com/nicolaskruchten/pivottable/issues/599

quoting the conclusion here for completeness:

> This is not really a reasonable thing to do... Think about it: a
>   5000x5000 table is not something a human can read. If each cell was 1
>   pixel by 1 pixel, you would need a grid of 3x5 HDTVs to display this
>   many pixels!